# "Select lemma font" error when using eledmac with Devanagari package

Tags: eledmac

I am making a critical edition of a Sanskrit text in Devanagari script using eledmac and the "devanagari" package.  Something about the Devanagari package messes with eledmac, and I get an error that reads: "Argument of `\select@@@lemmafont` has an extra `}`."  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}

@dollars

\beginnumbering

\autopar

$tatra bhagavAM punarapi candraprabhaM kumArabhUtamAmantrayate$ \edtext{$sma$}{\Afootnote{$rmma$}}$||$

\end{document}
```

Here is a MWE with an empty footnote before the devanagari text, which for some reason lets it compile properly:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}

@dollars

\beginnumbering

\autopar

\edtext{}{\Afootnote{}}$tatra bhagavAM punarapi candraprabhaM kumArabhUtamAmantrayate$ \edtext{$sma$}{\Afootnote{$rmma$}}$||$

\end{document}
```

Comment: which version of eledmac do you use? with your MWE + eledmac 1.16.0 (the last in CTAN) I have no problem.

Comment: I'm assuming you ran the MWE through the devanagari preprocessor?  If you don't run it, it will compile, but in order for the text in devanagari to come out properly, you need to run it through the preprocessor.  This seems to be where there is a problem.  Also, I noticed that if I add a footnote before any devanagari text, it will compile properly.  The only thing is that then there will be an empty footnote at the beginning of the footnotes, which doesn't look nice.  

I have the 2014 LaTeX distribution, I'm assuming this has the latest version of eledmac.

Thank you!

Comment: you didn't explain that devanagari has a pre-processor, and everyone doesn't know it. So change your question. I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I don't understand anything to denavagari. However, understanding that I should use the pre-processor, (what you should have explained in your question), I obtain, with you MWE, this real MWE, after pre-processor using.

```
\def\DevnagVersion{2.15}\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}

%@dollars

\beginnumbering

\autopar

{\dn t/ BgvA\2 \7{p}nrEp c\306w\qb{d}\3FEwB\2 \7{k}mAr\8{B}tmAm\306w/yt\?} \edtext{{\dn -m}}{\Afootnote{{\dn Mm\0}}}{\dn ..}

\end{document}
```

That is the real MWE which doesn't work. If you look carefully to the handbook of eledmac, you can read (p. 12) actualy :

> \autopar fails, however, on paragraphs that start with a { or with any
>   other command that starts a new group before it generates any text.
>   Such paragraphs need to be started explicitly, before the new group is
>   opened, using \indent, \noindent, or \leavevmode, or using \pstart
>   itself

That is the case here. So just add \pstart before the $ in you pre-pre-processor file.

Comment: you're welcome. I will publish a release which inform about \edtext outside of \pstart.